# Efficiently determine indices of middle 0's for consecutive 0's in an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

Given an array consisting of non-negative numbers, I want to be able to find the index of the middle 0 for each of the consecutive 0's in the array, excluding 0's that are found at the start or the end of the array. A simple example: we have given array

```
np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0])
```

Then, I want to return indices 6 and 13 (for an even amount of consecutive 0's, I want either the floor or ceil).

Now, my current implementation is as follows:

```
def middle_zero(array):
    busy = False
    not_start_zero = False

    middle_zero_list = []

    for i in range(len(array)):
        if array[i] > 0:
            not_start_zero = True

        if array[i] == 0 and not_start_zero and not busy:
            start = i
            busy = True
        if busy and array[i] > 0:
            end = i
            middle_zero_list.append(int(np.mean([start, end])))
            busy = False

    return np.array(middle_zero_list)
```

```
middle_zero(np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0]))
>> array([6, 13])
```

Although it is working, I think that a much more clever solution is possible here. As I have to do this computation many times, I want it to be more efficient.

Comment: Seems like a great usecase for [`numba.njit`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html). Have you tried that?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I forgot to mention that I only want to consider consecutive zeros that are not at the start and not at the end of the array. When those are left out of consideration, is there still a bug?

Comment: does it deal with negative numbers as required? eg ```middle_zero(np.array([0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, -3, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0]))``` gives ```array([8])``` so it's not the middle of zeros, it's the middle of non positives

Comment: Good point @Nin17. I did not mention that I only consider arrays consisting of non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note this doesn't include solitary non-positives, ie `middle_zero(np.array([1,0,2]))` gives `array([], dtype=float64)`

If you want a numpy only solution, you could do this (which shows significant speed improvements if the input array is large though it's slower than @DominikStańczak answer using numba (actually it depends on input - see below) - you can also use numba with this though it doesn't speed it up much):

```
import numpy as np
def middle_zero(array):
    argwhere = np.argwhere(array > 0).ravel()

    diff = np.ediff1d(argwhere)
    result = argwhere[:-1]+diff//2 # Or argwhere[:-1]+np.ceil(diff/2) for consistency with OP

    return result[result != argwhere[:-1]] #Or result[result-1 != argwhere[:-1]] for consistency with OP
```

Output with given example:

```
array([ 6, 12])
```

Edit timings:
with input as `np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0])`

```
25.1 µs ± 227 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each) #OP
11.8 µs ± 30.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each) #Nin17
1.18 µs ± 3.97 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each) #Dominik
```

With input as `np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 2, size=100000)`

```
225 ms ± 1.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) #OP
833 µs ± 3.76 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) #Nin17
481 µs ± 2.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) #Dominik
```

If you have long regions of consecutive non-positive numbers, this is actually the fastest, with an input of `np.array([1,*[0]*1000,1]*1000)`:

```
539 ms ± 1.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) #OP
432 µs ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) #Nin17
1.93 ms ± 2.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each) #Dominik
```

Comment: Awesome, nice to see a numpy solution, and that it scales better than numba, as expected! Can I ask why did you go with `ediff1d` vs `diff` here?

Comment: I used ```ediff1d``` instead of ```diff``` because ```diff``` isn't [supported by numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html) so you can also ```njit``` this to make it slightly faster. I think it works the same with ```diff``` without numba.

Answer (score 2):

Simply wrapping your function in `numba.njit` (replacing the `np.mean` with a direct computation) gets this a nice speedup:

```py
[nav] In [8]: @numba.njit
         ...: def middle_zero2(array):
         ...:     busy = False
         ...:     not_start_zero = False
         ...:
         ...:     middle_zero_list = []
         ...:
         ...:     for i in range(len(array)):
         ...:         if array[i] > 0:
         ...:             not_start_zero = True
         ...:
         ...:         if array[i] == 0 and not_start_zero and not busy:
         ...:             start = i
         ...:             busy = True
         ...:         if busy and array[i] > 0:
         ...:             end = i
         ...:             middle_zero_list.append(int((start+end)/2))
         ...:             busy = False
         ...:
         ...:     return np.array(middle_zero_list)

[ins] In [10]: %timeit middle_zero(a)
24.3 µs ± 466 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# skipped a cache run

[ins] In [12]: %timeit middle_zero2(a)
763 ns ± 20.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

about a factor of 30 of a speedup on your small example test case.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dominik! Although this already results in a speedup, I think that there might be a more clever solution possible (e.g. leaving out the for loop). Do you also have any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is faster, but should be metered.
It should be faster on a compiled language, but python is not.

```
def middle_zero(array):
    busy = False
    not_start_zero = False
    start=None
    end=None

    middle_zero_list = []

    for i, value in enumerate(array):
        isZero = value == 0
        not_start_zero = [True, not_start_zero][isZero]

        start, busy = [[start, busy], [i, True]][isZero and not_start_zero and not busy]
        if busy and not isZero:
            end = i
            middle_zero_list.append(int(np.mean([start, end])))
            busy = False

    return np.array(middle_zero_list)
```

Comment: This is slower than OPs